# Similarity Measure in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I am working on this coding challenge named **Similarity Measure**. Now the problem is my code works fine for some test cases, and **failed due to the Time Limit Exceed** problem. However, my code is not wrong, takes more than 25 sec for input of **range 10^4**.

I need to know what I can do to make it more efficient, I cannot think on any better solution than my code.

Question goes like this:

> Problems states that given an array of positive integers, and now we have to answer based upon the Q queries.
>
> Query: Given two indices L,R, determine the maximum absolute difference of index of two same elements lies between L and R
>
> If in a range, there are no two same inputs then return 0
>
> INPUT FORMAT
>
> The first line contains N, no. of elements in the array A
>   The Second line contains N space separated integers that are elements of the array A
>   The third line contains Q the number of queries
>   Each of the Q lines contains L, R
>
> CONSTRAINTS
>
> ```
> 1 <= N, Q <= 10^4
> 1 <= Ai <= 10^4
> 1 <= L, R <= N
> ```
>
> OUTPUT FORMAT
>
> For each query, print the ans in a new line
>
> Sample Input
>
> ```
> 5
> 1 1 2 1 2
> 5
> 2 3
> 3 4
> 2 4
> 3 5
> 1 5
> ```
>
> Sample Output
>
> ```
> 0
> 0
> 2
> 2
> 3
> ```
>
> Explanation
>
> ```
> [2,3] - No two elements are same
> [3,4] - No two elements are same
> [2,4] - there are two 1's so ans = |4-2| = 2
> [3,5] - there are two 2's so ans = |5-3| = 2
> [1,5] - there are three 1's and two 2's so ans = max(|4-2|, |5-3|, |4-1|, |2-1|) = 3
> ```

Here is my algorithm:

> 1. To take the input and test the range in a different method
> 2. Input will be L, R and the Array
> 3. For difference between L and R equal to 1, check if the next element is equal, return 1 else return 0
> 4. For difference more than 1, loop through array
> 5. Make a nested loop to check for the same element, if yes, store the difference into maxVal variable
> 6. Return maxVal

**My Code:**

```
def ansArray(L, R, arr):
    maxVal = 0
    if abs(R - L) == 1:
        if arr[L-1] == arr[R-1]: return 1
        else: return 0
    else:
        for i in range(L-1, R):
          for j in range(i+1, R):
              if arr[i] == arr[j]:
                 if (j-i) > maxVal: maxVal = j-i
        return maxVal

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input()
    arr = (input().split())

    for i in range(int(input())):
        L, R = input().split()
        print(ansArray(int(L), int(R), arr))
```

Please help me with this. I really want to learn a different and a more efficient way to solve this problem. Need to pass all the TEST CASES. :)

Comment: Any time you say nested loop, you've got a problem. You can probably do this in O(n), but even sorting will give O(n log n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
import collections


def ansArray(L, R, arr):
    dct = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for index in range(L - 1, R):
        dct[arr[index]].append(index)
    return max(lst[-1] - lst[0] for lst in dct.values())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    input()
    arr = (input().split())

    for i in range(int(input())):
        L, R = input().split()
        print(ansArray(int(L), int(R), arr))
```

Explanation:

`dct` is a dictionary that for every seen number keeps a list of indices. The list is sorted so `lst[-1] - lst[0]` will give maximum absolute difference for this number. Applying `max` to all this differences you get the answer. Code complexity is O(R - L).

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved as O(N) approximately the following way:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def ansArray(L, R, arr) :
    # collect the positions and save them into the dictionary
    positions = defaultdict(list)
    for i,j in enumerate(arr[L:R+1]) :
        positions[j].append(i)

    # create the list of the max differences in index
    max_diff = list()
    for vals in positions.values() :
        max_diff.append( max(vals) - min(vals) )

    # now return the max element from the list we have just created
    if len(max_diff) :
        return max(max_diff)
    else :
        return 0
```